# Preserve DrawingArea 'image' on draw signal

Tags: c++, cairo, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I am trying to make simple square where you could paint with mouse. Problem is, whenever draw signal is happens, cairo surface seems to be cleared entirely. I understand this because after first `queue_draw()` white background is gone and I see my GTK theme color (which is grey).

I thought I could save surface or context, but you can't just create empty surface in cairo, and I can't create it using `this->get_window()->create_cairo_surface()` (where `this` is object of class inherited from `Gtk::DrawingArea`) because when constructor is called, widget isn't attached to any window yet, so it is a null pointer. I mean, I could create some public function called `you_are_added_to_window_create_cairo_surface()` but I'd really like not to do this.

So I really don't know what to do and what I don't understand about cairo.

How do I preserve, or save 'canvas' current state, so whatever is actually being drawn is just applied on existing drawing?

Here is callback function of my class:

```
bool MyDrawingArea::on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> & cr) {
    /* clear and fill background with white in the beginning */
    if (first_draw) {
        cr->save();
        cr->set_source_rgb(255.0, 255.0, 255.0);
        cr->paint();
        cr->restore();

        first_draw = false;
    }

    cr->save();

    cr->set_source_rgb(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    cr->begin_new_path();
    while (!dots_queue.empty()) {
        auto dot = dots_queue.front();
        cr->line_to(dot.first, dot.second);
        dots_queue.pop();
    }
    cr->close_path();
    cr->stroke();

    cr->restore();

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So while storing all actions works, it's really not ok if you are trying to have your program save your drawings, you will have to use second surface to save everything on.

My solution combines both answers of Uli Schlachter.

First, I have structure, in which I store last drawing action, since last Button Press, and until Button Release. This allows me to show things such as lines in real time, while keeping canvas clean of it.

Second, I store everything drawn on canvas on a surface, which is created like that:

```
// this - is object of class, derived from DrawingArea
auto allocation = this->get_allocation(); 

this->surface = Cairo::ImageSurface::create(
    Cairo::Format::FORMAT_ARGB32,
    allocation.get_width(),
    allocation.get_height()
);
```

Then, on each `draw` signal, I restore it like that:

```
cr->save();
cr->set_source(surface, 0.0, 0.0);
cr->paint();
cr->restore();
```

Whenever I want to save surface, i.e. apply drawing on to canvas, I do the following:

```
Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> t_context = Cairo::Context::create(surface);
t_context->set_source(cr->get_target(), -allocation.get_x(), -allocation.get_y());
t_context->paint();
```

Here is the important moment. Without adjusting for the allocation coordinates, your canvas is going to slide away on each surface save and restore.

With that, I can easily keep my drawings on canvas, load canvas from file (because I am using ImageSurface), or save it to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `first_draw` and instead of `dots_queue.pop()`, just iterate over the `dots_queue` and redraw all of them each time.

The `draw` function is not meant for "I want to add some drawing". Instead, it is "hey, the windowing system has no idea what should be drawn here, please fill this with content". That's why the cairo surface is cleared.

Comment: I thought about that, but isn't it going to create huuuuge overhead in a long run? I mean, my application is not designed for big drawings, rather small sketches, but anyway...

Comment: I don't even want to try to imagine how long one has to sketch before that becomes a problem, but okay: Alternatively, you could create a cairo image surface, draw to that and only copy this surface in your `on_draw` handler. However, what do you do when your window is resized?

Comment: Okay, you are right - I tried scribbling for like 5 minutes and approximately it took around 150k of memory. Not really good, but I haven't even tried optimizing memory. Thanks!